# QR code scanning not working in titanium appcelerator iPhone using tibar - Zbar

Tags: ios, titanium

I am developing QR code scanner kind of application in titanium.

I have used tibar - Zbar integration module for Titanium Mobile and as [this](http://code.google.com/p/tibar/) link guides, my Titanium SDK and iOS SDK fulfills the criteria this solution ask for but unfortunately it is not working.

Please suggest other good solutions you have with you for QR Code scan app in Titanium Appcelerator.

Error i am getting is:

```
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.5/iphone/builder.py", line 1222, in main
    execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=__LOG__ID__=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr)],False)
  File "/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.5/iphone/builder.py", line 1140, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.5/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this module this is working fine
[QR SCanner](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/770?1097351001) for Best Result

Comment: thanks for your quick response... As u might know this module is not free so is there any other free module available in market, which can be used?

Comment: no, this time i have no Idea for Free QR Reader Module in Appcelerator Titanium. But, this is buy only 1 time and use one application life time.

Comment: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/2808?1897544046 You Can use this module also. :) Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

System Exit 65 is often and SDK error, try using a different SDK.